# Нужны ли кавычки в названии мероприятий?

Tags: названия, кавычки

Нужны ли кавычки в названии мероприятий.
Например, В школе состоялся День открытых дверей.
В школе будут проведены два мероприятия- "Лучший по профессии" и "День открытых дверей".
Награждается **_**_ за участие в Дне открытых дверей. В каком случае в названии мероприятий нужно ставить кавычки, в каком нет.

Comment: @Верьясова, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Прежде всего разберемся в наименованиях. Наименования разделены на две группы: 
Составные названия, не являющиеся условными, -  ***реальные собственные имена (в терминологии А. В. Суперанской).*** В таких названиях все слова употребляются в прямом значении. Кавычками такие названия не выделяются; в них пишется с прописной буквы первое слово и входящие в состав наименования имена собственные. Например: ***Государственный Русский музей.*** Такие наименования отличаются синтаксическая  сочетаемостью.

> ***Условные (символические) названия, заключаемые в кавычки.***
> Напр.: театр ''Современник'', театр ''Школа современной пьесы'' .Такие наименования не сочетаются синтаксически с родовым словом и берутся в кавычки. 
>  Обратимся к вашим примерам.
>
> ***В школе состоялся День открытых дверей.*** *В этом примере присутствует синтаксическая сочетаемость, поэтому кавычки не нужны.*  ***В школе будут проведены два мероприятия- "Лучший по профессии" и "День открытых дверей",   -*** э*ти примеры, в отличии от первого, относятся к второй группе, т.е. представляют собой условные наименования и, следовательно, заключаются в кавычки.*

Answer (score 1):

> В школе состоялся День открытых
>   дверей.
>
> В школе будут проведены два
>   мероприятия- "Лучший по профессии" и
>   "День открытых дверей".
>
> Награждается __ за участие в Дне
>   открытых дверей.

Вообще-то словари, в том числе и "Русский орфографический словарь" (4-е изд., 2012 г.), требуют написание ***дня открытых дверей*** со строчной и без кавычек.  Но не всегда строчная смотрится уместно, часто ***День*** встречается и с прописной, в том числе и в учебниках (https://books.google.ru/books?id=yCrqAAAAMAAJ&q=%22%D0%B2+%D0%94%D0%BD%D0%B5+%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8B%D1%85+%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%22&dq=%22%D0%B2+%D0%94%D0%BD%D0%B5+%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8B%D1%85+%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%22&hl=ru&sa=X&ei=S54BVeTZBMjMygP07IFo&redir_esc=y ):

[image]

===

В  первом Вашем предложении я бы постарался обойтись без кавычек  и прописной:

***В школе состоялся день открытых дверей.***

Во втором  как минимум  добавил бы слово ***конкурс*** (или в школе запланирован не конкурс?):

***В школе будут проведены два мероприятия -- конкурс "Лучший по профессии" и "День открытых дверей".***

Или бы вообще перестроил предложение:

***...будут проведены  день открытых дверей  и конкурс "Лучший по профессии".***

Третье оставил бы в таком виде, как у Вас есть.